# SPI, RS232 and DMX-512 data signals beneath the ESP8266-WROOM-02 Wifi antenna

Tags: pcb-design, wifi, emc, pcb-antenna

I am working on [DMX-512 Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMX512), which will accept commands for driving [Addressable LED strip (GE60RGBW8812A)](http://www.gree-leds.com/productshow.asp?ArticleID=R3PV8V94P3) via [ESP-WROOM-02 Wifi Controller](https://www.espressif.com/en/products/hardware/esp-wroom-02/overview) and I have several data lines (`SPI`, `RS232` and `DMX-512`) *under* `ESP-WROOM-02's` on-chip antenna:
[image: PCB Antenna]
Here is another, zoomed and layer-filtered image:
[image: PCB Antenna zoomed]
And another screenshot for clarification:
[image: PCB without rastnet]
This is my first `Wifi` PCB design and my guts tell me I've done horrible mistake placing these data lines *under* the mentioned PCB antenna. Should I reroute data lines or is this design ok?

Comment: I think the antenna should hang off the edge of your board, and be adjacent to a ground plane on your main PCB.

Comment: @HarrySvensson I've added 2nd image for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should check out the [ESP32 Hardware Design Guidelines](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_hardware_design_guidelines_en.pdf), where they clearly show ideal and non-ideal positioning of a module like the WROOM on a carrier PCB:
[image: Module over-hang preferred]

But if you can't let the module's PCB antenna over-hang due to whatever constraints of your overall design requirements, then this guideline is the fall-back option:
[image: Module wholly within the carrier PCB]

The 'keep-out zone' is where you have no components, no copper (no tracks, no planes, nothing), nothing but bare PCB.

So no, any tracks (and other metals) near the WROOM's PCB-antenna will negatively impact wireless performance, and also have wifi/bluetooth signals coupling at point blank range to your other digital signals.

P.S. Perhaps in future hold off for a day or two before awarding a correct answer, until there are a few answers to choose from :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this will affect the RF performance, MIFA type antennas typically need a minimum amount of free space around them to get best performance and they really don't like ground/power planes directly underneath.  It's not as much as one would think, but you also should consider whatever case design you have, etc.  Reference materials are available easiest way to get them is to go either here:
https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/espressif-systems/ESP-WROOM-02/1904-1009-1-ND/8544304?utm_adgroup=RF%20&%20RFID
Note the placement design guide and datasheet pdf docs.

Note that your current layout will most likely still transmit/receive a signal that operates over a (perhaps severely) reduced range so you could still find some use if you've already ordered the board design.